# send array of image using Multi Part Entity in android

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartentity

I want to send array of image using multi part entity
like  want to send more than one image.
argument of signature is give below

```
entity.addPart("files[]", .....);
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP mime](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3) library(Preferable 4.3.3) and HTTP post to upload the file to the server.
The PHP server will recognize the image as FILE which is required in your case.
I have created a class which helps me to upload the image or any file to my server

```
public class FileUploadHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;
    private String URL;

    public FileUploadHelper(String URL) {
        multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            multipartEntity.addTextBody("<YOUR STRING KEY>", "<STRING VALUE>");

            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            HttpClient httpclient;
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addFile(String key, File newFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            multipartEntity.addBinaryBody(key, newFile);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No file was found at the path " + newFile.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

To use this class create Object of FileUploader class, then call its addFile() function and call execute() as this class extends AsyncTask. In your code you already have File object as

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
```

Just pass this object to addFile(). The key for the addFile() will be "files[]" which is required for you.
Note that you may not able to send array of file in one blow, because the key files[] will be override by the next one, so only last image will get uploaded, so it is preferable to send request multiple times with the same  key "files[]" depending on how many files you have to send

Hope this will help you